# Using {{URL:to()}}, {{URL::asset}} or {{HTML::script}} in Laravel 5.6?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6

I want to have the following code:

`<script src="'js/custom.js'"></script>`

And I achieve this using blade syntax:

`<script src="{{ URL::to('js/custom.js') }}"></script>`

**or**

`<script src="{{ URL::asset('js/custom.js') }}"></script>`

**or**

`{{ HTML::script('js/custom.js') }}`

What's the difference between them?

And which way I **should use** in Laravel 5.6?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve this. the way you've used in the description is called facads. The most convenient way is to use helper functions available with laravel framework.

### asset() v secure_asset()

**asset()**

The asset function generates a URL for an asset using the current scheme of the request (HTTP or HTTPS):

```
$url = asset('img/photo.jpg');
```

**secure_asset()**

The secure_asset function generates a URL for an asset using HTTPS:

```
$url = secure_asset('img/photo.jpg');
```

### **url() vs secure_url()**

**secure_url()**

The secure_url function generates a fully qualified HTTPS URL to the given path:

```
$url = secure_url('user/profile');

$url = secure_url('user/profile', [1]);
```

**url()**

The url function generates a fully qualified URL to the given path:

```
$url = url('user/profile');

$url = url('user/profile', [1]);
```

If no path is provided, a Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator instance is returned:

```
$current = url()->current();

$full = url()->full();

$previous = url()->previous();
```

### To inject assests in to the blade

**Scripts**

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/admin/app.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/bootstrap3-typeahead.min.js') }}"></script>
```

**Styles**

```
<link href="{{ asset('css/admin/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

$path = public_path();

$path = public_path('css/app.css');

Answer (score 3):

the `asset()` method is used to include CSS/JavaScript/images files, you can use it in this cases

```
<link href="{{ asset('css/min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="{{ asset('use.typekit.net/zjb5wvv.js') }}"></script>
<img alt="logo" src="{{ asset('images/logo.png') }}">
The files must located in the public folder.
```

the `url()` method used to generate an url to a link, `{{ url('users', ['page' => 22], $secure = null) }}`

Comment: Thanks, and do you know how I should use HTML::script?